# make new partition table

Tags: mbr

I,m an amateur web programmer and ignorant on linux advanved features.

gdisk shows that i have only MBR type partition table.

Is there any solution to make a new partition table without loosing my drives contents?

I want to install ubuntu side of my win7 that is installed.but ubuntu installer doesn't show my partitions althought i removed gpt stray.

Meantime my MBR boot is corrupted and ican't log in windows.it's not the problem,but maybe related or cause of problem.

I used fixparts,gdisk or anything else it was.i had to study 10 articles about this commands at day for the fear of loosing data.

Is it practicable to solve the problem by creating new partition table?

Comment: I can't follow what you have done nor figure out what you are really asking, unless it is "I broke my partition table somehow, how do I fix it?", which is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: Post this to see partitions: sudo parted -l  Most Windows 7 systems use all 4 primary MBR(msdos) partitions and that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix your MBR. I recommend you try Fixing it using [THIS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)   (i recommend you created the boot-repair bootable method, that worked for me)

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
```

THen see if ubuntu sees your partitions, or Make one using gparted and your bootable (Install Gparted on your bootable using:)    (Before using this command make sure that you are connected to the internet)

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

If anything else comes up, let me know

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Festplatten_Problembehebung

sounds like a partionlos? 
google testdisk to find more help.

or

```
apt-get install testdisk
```

if you woud like to grow/shrink your pation then use the right tools (ntfs - resize should be done on Windows) for others look at resize2fs

Comment: you can use gnome-disks if you like GUIs. for resize

Comment: He also wants to fix his MBR. BTW

Comment: MBR repair of Windows will only Work on Windows, Data rescue can be done on Linux. - You have to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

I would first repair your MBR with Windows DVD.

After you repaired your MBR, check if Win8 is booting. Backup externaly all important stuff. Now you can create a minimum/recommended 8GB big FAT32 partition under Windows for use with Ubuntu and some 2GB FAT 32 for Ubuntu SWAP.

BEWARE: If you resize  Windows made partitions under Ubuntu, your MBR will get corrupted.

Then install Ubuntu, manually chose xyGB partition to instal and 2GB for SWAP.

If you choose partitions correctly, no data loss is involved.